# Printing an object within an array showing as blank

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, output

```
function displayEvent(array) {
var vOutput = "";
var ind = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    ind += 1;
    vOutput += "Name " + ind + ": " + array[i].name + ", Age " + array[i].age + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = vOutput;
}
function init() {
var arrEvent = [];
var objEvent = {};
objEvent.name = prompt("Enter name of Event");
objEvent.age = prompt("Enter number of Guests");
arrEvent.push(objEvent);
while(objEvent.name.length > 0) {
    objEvent.name = prompt("Enter name of Event");
    objEvent.age = prompt("Enter number of Guests");
    if(objEvent.name.length > 0) {
        arrEvent.push(objEvent);
    }
}
displayEvent(arrEvent);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Trying to print an object array into the HTML paragraph id and whenever I execute the code above I get the correct output but the array elements just show as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always pushing the same object into your array.

Change to:

```
function displayEvent(array) {
var vOutput = "";
var ind = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    ind += 1;
    vOutput += "Name " + ind + ": " + array[i].name + ", Age " + array[i].age + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = vOutput;
}
function init() {
var arrEvent = [];
var name = '';
var age = '';
name = prompt("Enter name of Event");
age = prompt("Enter number of Guests");
arrEvent.push({name: name, age: age});
while(name.length > 0) {
    name = prompt("Enter name of Event");
    age = prompt("Enter number of Guests");
    if(name.length > 0) {
        arrEvent.push({name: name, age: age});
    }
}
displayEvent(arrEvent);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked! Just had to remove the objEvent from the conditions of the if and while statements to make it work :)

Comment: @PYUO Yes! Edited.